# Long content in Tables

Tags: tables, html, css, text

What is the best way maximize readability when displaying variations of long/short text within table?

Comment: Can you explain further exactly what you mean in this case? Also, what is your target display? Readable on a phone isn't the same as readable on a TV isn't the same as readable on a desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a **read more...** link after 250 characters, which would make it easier for the user to scan the entire list.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSnqd4.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Great answer! Is there any jQuery plugins to help achieve this solution?

Comment: Thanx. That would be the jQuery Expander Plugin http://www.devcurry.com/2010/12/add-read-more-link-using-jquery.html